# Angular + net Core Application with both SPA and MPA approaches

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a aspnet Core application with angular which is created using the sample from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular

I want to serve some pages from server, how can I do that on my root application path and use the angular application in a subPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply **create a branch middleware to serve spa files**:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

const string subappPath = "/subPath";

app.Map(subappPath,appBuilder =>{
    appBuilder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.DefaultPage = subappPath+"/index.html";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions{
            RequestPath = subappPath,

        };
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});
```

And then **change the `<base>` of `ClientApp/src/index.html` to `/subPath/`** :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/subPath/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

(Note : **the trailing `/` of `/subPath/` is required**!)

---

Lastly, you might need to edit some of your hard-coded api endpoints. For example, the default `fetch-data` component will send request to `http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')`. It's likely that you might want to change the ajax call to `'/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts'`, or create server routes with a `/subPath/api` prefix if you like.