# Angular + dotnet 7 application with both spa and mpa approaches

Tags: .net, angular

I ran into the same issue as described in this question:
[Angular + net Core Application with both SPA and MPA approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394436/angular-net-core-application-with-both-spa-and-mpa-approaches)

I would like to ask if there is a newer/better solution using dotnet version 7. The method appBuilder.UseSpa mentioned there does not seem to exist any more, because the spa nowadays is configured in the csproject file and other places.

I tried the solution mentioned and multiple attempts to change the configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does exist in .NET 7, you have to install:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="7.0.2" />
```